# Some vue scripts in a blade page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I would like to add some dynamism to my blade pages. For example if I select a certain value in a select, then make certain inputs of the form appear or disappear.

I told myself that this is an opportunity to put some "vue" functionnalities in my pages, to learn.

To do this I followed what is indicated in the doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vue

I installed vue in my project : `npm install vue@next`
I modified my "webpack.mix.js" in which I specify that I am using vue :

```
mix.js('resources/js/main_js.js', 'public/js')
.vue()
```

When I `run npm watch` : all is OK, I have no errors. Perfect !

Naively I just created a simple script to see if it worked, and before going any further. In a blade page I just added that :

```
<script>
    Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return { count: 1 }
  },
  created() {
    // `this` points to the vm instance
    console.log('count is: ' + this.count) // => "count is: 1"
  }
})
```

And when I load the page I have this error :
**Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined**

This is probably too simplistic an approach. But what am I missing for this little piece of code to work? When I understand the mechanics, I can go further. I'm sure I'm not far away!

Comment: You did load/reference your `main_js`, right?

Comment: Yes I reference the main_js. But I did not added anything in this file regarding vue. My mistake ?

Comment: Try to add `window.Vue = require('vue');` in `resources/js/main_js.js` and compile once.

Comment: It works ! Thanks Wilson. I do not know if it is the best practice to use vue like I do... but I am learning. Have a nice day.